# load a php image using src

Tags: php, image

Is it possible to load a image using:

```
<img src="image.php?image_id=1">
```

?

for `image.php`:

```
$image_id = $_GET['image_id']; 
echo "image".$image_id.".png";
```

Comment: Don't you mean src? I just corrected it.

Comment: answer to your question is yes

Comment: Are you sure you want to use server's resources to read then echo an image? I wouldn't be so sure about that...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you must return a valid image, use [file_get_contents](http://php.net/file_get_contents) or [readfile](http://php.net/readfile) for get the conent of image then output to browser

```
 header("Content-Type:image/png");

    $image_id = $_GET['image_id']; 

    if(is_file($file = "image".$image_id.".png") ||  is_file($file = "no_image.png"))
        readfile($file);
```

Comment: Don't serve up images with a `text/html` content-type.

Comment: output still needs the headers

Comment: Or, if this is not to hide the true image location, or if the image is not created on the fly, one could easily use the `Location` header to redirect to the image. (If it's accessable through http)

Answer (score 0):

If you have the png contents in the database, follow the other answers. If all you need is the id from the database, simply `<img src="image<?=$image_id?>.png">`

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible that way. You would have to write the contents of the image file to the output stream instead.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to load a image use:
>   `<img src="image.php?image_id=1">`

Yes. URLs are URLs. It is content-type that determines content, not any characters in the URL itself.

> `$image_id = $_GET['image_id'];`
>   `echo "image".$image_id.".png";`

Not like that. You either have to read the image file in and then output it with a suitable content-type, or redirect (with a location header) to a static image.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the header content-type and print the contents of the image file. Here is an example for your image.php file:

```
$image_id = $_GET['image_id']; 
$filename = "image".$image_id.".png"; 
header('Content-Type: image/png');
print file_get_contents($filename);
```

Answer (score 0):

one liner....

```
echo (file_exists($_GET['image_id'])) ? header("Content-Type:image/png").readfile($_GET['image_id']).die() : false;
```