# htaccess breaks my images?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm trying to rewrite a PHP file that dynamically displays images into .jpeg in the browser so it can look like an image path.

My problem is that after introducing the rewrite rule, the images break. When I check the source code the image path is correct, but all I see is the "broken image icon".

Help is very much appreciated!

Here is the .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^images/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\.jpeg$ image.php?id=$1
```

And here is the PHP/HTML code:

```
<?php

$imgname = ($_GET["id"]) . ".jpeg";
$imgpath = "images/" . $imgname; 

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>

<?php 

if (file_exists($imgpath)) {

   echo "<img src='" . $imgpath . "'" . " alt='image'></img>";

} else {

    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
}

 ?>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [Try reading the images bytes and serve it as the result with the proper header.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6028490/342740)

Comment: try accessing the image `image.php?id=xxxx` without any headers (aka comment out `header()` functions), you may have a php error in the `image.php`.

Comment: @RyanNaddy there is no error he is redirecting all images to the php file but he is not serving the image itself but an html that leads back to the image which obviously will not show the image because that is being redirect.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot serve an image with HTML content.

The following would be a minimalist version of how your script to properly deliver the image.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
readfile('images/' . $_GET['id'] . '.jpeg');
```

Of course you can put your checks into that, but keep in mind you have to deliver another image in case of error and not a webpage.

Answer (score 0):

After:

```
$imgname = ($_GET["id"]) . ".jpeg";
$imgpath = "images/" . $imgname;
```

Add:

```
if(file_exists($imgpath)) {
    header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
    readfile($imgpath);
    exit;
}

header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
```

Don't use any HTML there - for JPEG request server should response with only header(s) and actualy image content.